# Displaying line numbers in Pycharm 2016

Tags: ide, pycharm

I just got Pycharm 2016.1.2, and I cannot see the line numbers, in other versions of pycharm it was easy to change, but now it is in another menu or something and I cannot find it, do you know where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be found under:

```
Editor ---> General ---> Appearance
```

[image]